# Find if 2 triangles are perpendicular in 3D space

Tags: python, numpy, math, geometry, dot-product

I have 2 triangles in 3D space made of 3 points.

I assume I need to use the dot product but how do I arrange the matrix?

I think I have the pieces but need help to arrange it :)

Thank you.

Current code included below, not convinced it is correct.

```
vx1 = self.vertices[f[1]].x-self.vertices[f[0]].x
vy1 = self.vertices[f[1]].y-self.vertices[f[0]].y
vz1 = self.vertices[f[1]].z-self.vertices[f[0]].z

vx2 = self.vertices[f[2]].x-self.vertices[f[0]].x
vy2 = self.vertices[f[2]].y-self.vertices[f[0]].y
vz2 = self.vertices[f[2]].z-self.vertices[f[0]].z

plane1 = np.cross([vx1,vy1,vz1],[vx2, vy2, vz2])

vx3 = self.vertices[ff[1]].x-self.vertices[ff[0]].x
vy3 = self.vertices[ff[1]].y-self.vertices[ff[0]].y
vz3 = self.vertices[ff[1]].z-self.vertices[ff[0]].z

vx4 = self.vertices[ff[2]].x-self.vertices[ff[0]].x
vy4 = self.vertices[ff[2]].y-self.vertices[ff[0]].y
vz4 = self.vertices[ff[2]].z-self.vertices[ff[0]].z

plane2 = np.cross([vx3,vy3,vz3],[vx4, vy4, vz4])

print("p1",plane1)
print("p2",plane2)
print("dot",np.dot(plane1,plane2))

if np.dot(plane1,plane2) == 0:
    print("perpendictular")
```

Comment: Triangle 1 is made from (x1, y1, z1), (x2, y2, z2), (x3, y3, z3)
Triangle 2 is made from (xx1, yy1, zz1), (xx2, yy2, zz2), (xx3, yy3, zz3)

I assume I create 2 vectors for each triangle using (x2-x1,y2-y1,z2-z1) and (x3-x1, y3-y1, z3-z1) and similar for xx1 etc.

Comment: Your question seems to be more mathematical than about programming. It might be better placed at https://math.stackexchange.com .

Comment: What matrix are you asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rory Daulton's answer is intuitive and perfectly fine. I'd just add that you can use [Binet-Cauchy formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet%E2%80%93Cauchy_identity) for a ten-fold speedup:

```
import numpy as np

TR1, TR2 = np.random.random((2,3,3))

def xprod():
    return np.cross(*(TR1[:2]-TR1[2]))@np.cross(*(TR2[:2]-TR2[2]))

def bincau():
    aux = ((TR1[:2]-TR1[2])@(TR2[:2]-TR2[2]).T).ravel()
    return aux[0]*aux[3] - aux[1]*aux[2]

xprod()
# -0.04300263623056995
bincau()
# -0.043002636230569956

from timeit import timeit

timeit(xprod, number=100000)
# 7.751510428992333
timeit(bincau, number=100000)
# 0.620043026006897
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume here that the triangles do not need to actually intersect to be considered "perpendicular".

In that case, the triangles are perpendicular if and only if their normal vectors are perpendicular. To find the normal vector of Triangle 1, take the cross-product of the vectors making the sides. I.e. if Triangle 1 is defined by the points `t1p1`, `t1p2`, and `t1p3`, calculate the cross product of `t1p2-t1p1` and `t1p3-t1p1`. (Use `numpy.cross` to do that.) Do the same for Triangle 2.

Now use the dot product to see of those normal vectors are perpendicular to each other. (Use `numpy.dot` to do that.) Those vectors are perpendicular if their dot product is zero.

If your points have floating-point coordinates, you should check "close to zero" rather than "equal to zero" to handle slight calculation errors. I'll leave the actual Python/numpy code to you. If you need more help, show some more effort on your part.

Comment: Thank you. I had to cut lots out of the question as the webpage thought I was not using correct grammar when explaining my problem.

Comment: It was a rounding issue: if np.absolute(np.dot(plane1,plane2)) < 0.0001: