# Python Numpy not giving me expected result for angle between planes

Tags: python, numpy, 3d

I have 3 points on a plane, 3 points on another plane. I want the angle between the planes so I use the points to make vectors, cross product to find the normal, dot product and divide by magnitude and inverse cos to find me the angle.

I was expecting 45 or 0.785398 as the angle between the normal of the planes from the points. I get 0.6154797086703875

There must be something wrong with my logic, can anyone help please? Thank you.

```
 import numpy as np

 """

 y axis up page
 x axis to the right on page
 z axis towards user out of page

 point1 -1,1,0
 point2 1,1,0
 point3 1,1,1
 so horizontal plane at y=1

 point4 0,0,0
 point5 1,1,0
 point6 1,1,1
 plane at 45 degrees meeting other plane at 1,1,n

 """

 #use points to make vectors
 #point2 - point1
 vx1 = 2#1--1
 vy1 = 0#1-1
 vz1 = 0#0-0
 #point3 - point1
 vx2 = 2#1--1
 vy2 = 0#1-1
 vz2 = 1#1-0
 #cross product to find normal
 plane1 = np.cross([vx1,vy1,vz1],[vx2,vy2,vz2])

 #use points to make vectors
 #point5 - point4
 vx1 = 1#1-0
 vy1 = 1#1-0
 vz1 = 0#0-0
 #point6 - point4
 vx2 = 1#1-0
 vy2 = 1#1-0
 vz2 = 1#1-0
 #cross product to find normal
 plane2 = np.cross([vx1,vy1,vz1],[vx2,vy2,vz2])

 #angle between the two normals
 #dot product
 ang = np.dot(plane1,plane2)
 #divide by magnitude of vectors
 ang = ang / (np.sqrt((vx1*vx1)+(vy1*vy1)+(vz1*vz1))*np.sqrt((vx2*vx2)+(vy2*vy2)+(vz2*vz2)))
 #inverse cos to find angle
 ang = np.arccos(ang)
 #should be 45 or 0.785398
 print("Angle calculated",ang)
 if (ang < 95) and (ang > 85):
      print("RIGHT ANGLE")
 else:
      print("OTHER ANGLE")
```

Comment: You are normalizing by the wrong vectors. You should use the lengths of the normals (which you call plane1/2) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use `np.linalg.norm`:

```
ang = np.arccos(np.dot(plane1, plane2) / (np.linalg.norm(plane1) * np.linalg.norm(plane2)))
ang
>> 0.78539816
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments the error is that you are using the wrong vectors for normalization.

I'd like to add that [Binet-Cauchy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53797371/7207392) works here as well and is way faster than using cross product.

```
import math

def angle_BC(plane1, plane2):
    planes = np.concatenate((plane1[:2]-plane1[2], plane2[:2]-plane2[2]), axis=0)
    a = (planes@planes.T).ravel().tolist()
    return math.acos((a[2]*a[7]-a[3]*a[6]) / math.sqrt((a[0]*a[5]-a[1]*a[1])*(a[10]*a[15]-a[11]*a[11])))... 

def angle_CP(plane1, plane2):
    n1 = np.cross(*plane1[:2]-plane1[2])
    n2 = np.cross(*plane2[:2]-plane2[2])
    return math.acos(n1@n2 / math.sqrt(n1@n1 * n2@n2))

plane1, plane2 = np.array(((-1,1,0),(1,1,0),(1,1,1))), np.array(((0,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,1,1)))
angle_BC(plane1, plane2), angle_CP(plane1, plane2), np.pi/4
# (0.7853981633974484, 0.7853981633974484, 0.7853981633974483)

from timeit import repeat
min(repeat(lambda: angle_BC(plane1, plane2), number=10000))
# 0.08035301300697029
min(repeat(lambda: angle_CP(plane1, plane2), number=10000))
# 0.9213669009623118
```